# Moving option value on top of dropdown list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
  function SelectReferralFromQueryString() {
    var queryStringName = GetParameterValues('Referral');

    if (queryStringName != undefined || queryStringName != null) {
         queryStringName = decodeURIComponent(queryStringName);

       var exists = false;
       $('#refDropDown option').each(function () {
           if (this.value == queryStringName) {
               exists = true;
               var option = $(this);
               $(this).remove();
               $('#refDropDown option').prepend(option);
               return false;
           }
       });

       if (exists == true){
           DropDownReferral.value = queryStringName;
           $("#refDropDown").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }

}

function GetParameterValues(param) {
    var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
        if (urlparam[0] == param) {
            return urlparam[1];
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<select name="refDropDown" id="refDropDown" class="items" data-hidden-field="DropDownReferral">
     <option value="">Please Select</option>
     <option value="Albert">Al</option>
     <option value="Steve T">Steve</option>
</select>
```

So, the logic is:

1. If 'Referral' which is a query string, gets passed, then I am checking the value in my select option and moving it on top and disabling the dropdown. **NOT WORKING!** See the picture below.

[image]

2. If the dropdown doesnt have the query string value then disable the dropdown and store it in the hidden field. **(WORKING!)**

What I am missing here?

If I am passing ?Referral=Albert, then it should show me 'Al' on top. If I am passing ?Referral=Steve, then is show 'Steve' on top and disable the dropdown.

Comment: Why  $(this).remove(); ???

Comment: Whats wrong with just setting the selected prop? why so complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the val() function of jQuery to select the option:

```
$("#refDropDown").val(queryStringName);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! One line WORKED like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on the referral being a valid value you can try this (untested):

```
$('#refDropDown').val(queryStringName).prop('disabled', true);
```

Otherwise check for whether or not the value exists first by doing something like this:

```
if($('#refDropDown option[value="' + queryStringName + '"]').length != 0){ 
     //code above here 
}
```

Then get rid of that loop over the options and that `if` that is setting the select box to disabled.

Also as a side note, a disabled select box won't submit a value when you submit the form, so you will need to use the referral parameter, or a hidden field.